# Joomla не определяет пользователей из Аctive Directory работающих на Альт Линукс 10

Tags: joomla, windows-8, altlinux

Есть версия Joomla 3.9.5 в качестве внутреннего портал компании. Пользователи под Windows 8.1 заходят на сайт, где происходит их аутентификация на основе AD, и соответственно принадлежность к группам, определяющие их доступ к разделам на портале.
В связи с импортозамещением, меняем Win на Альт Линукс 10 версии. Появились проблемы. Пользователей не может определить автоматически, просит ввести логин-пароль. Если ввести, то заходит на сайт, но только в режиме гостя.
На настройках портала в разделе пользователи этот человек не отображается что он зашел.
Из-за этого разграничение прав не работает и люди не могут получить доступ к своим нужным разделам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел. Оказываться предыдущий системный администратор использовал не стандартную LDAP аутентификацию Joomla, а сторонний модуль shmanic LDAP. Так как пользователей линукс мы переносили в другое Organisation Unit, то в графе Binding настроек этого модуля, привязка была к старому OU, соответсвенно он их и не видел. Убрал нижний уровень, чтобы сканировал OU на уровень выше и OU Linux пользователей и OU Windows.